# Как будет правильнее, с точки зрения правил русского языка?

Tags: правила, времена, периоды-времени

Решила для себя написать рассказ. Но возникла проблема с одним предложением: Девушка тут же метнулась к шкафу, который располагается слева от стола.

Подруга поправила меня, сказав, что лучше будет звучать не "располагается", а "располагался", ведь события происходят в прошлом. Но мне хотелось бы узнать не как красивее, а как правильнее. Заранее благодарю всех, кто откликнется.

Comment: Правильнее так, как красивее. Почти всегда так.

Comment: Шкаф может находиться, занимать место, а располагаться — то, что множественно: группа компаний, апартаменты, гости. /// Приезжие занимают любимый стол, к которому привыкли, располагаясь на разлатых диванах; Сейчас в вилле Ля Рош располагается коллекция Фонда Ле Корбюзье.

Comment: Пишите: "девушка тут же метнулась к шкафу слева от стола". Меньше мусора  — качественнее текст.

Comment: @shampar В Нацкорпусе [много примеров](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=который+располагается) с единственным числом. Не надо здесь ограничивать возможности слова.

Comment: Не надо плодить неправильность, увеличивая кол-во примеров. Эти примеры неоднозначны: часто *это* слово говорит о величии персонажа, называющего себя на вы, а где-то ед. число (музей) подразумевает делимость (залы).

Comment: @shampar Да, при множественном числе звучит удачнее, но где запрещается использовать при единственном? [100 страниц](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&mode=main&nodia=1&p=0&req=располагается&sort=i_grstd&text=lexform).

Comment: Нет запрета. Есть ощущение непонимания смысла слова, а оно, употреблённое в отношении к предмету или персоне, всегда иронично: *Основной костюм расположился на трех вешалках в нише ― пальто, пиджак, брюки, жилет, рубашка*; *С этими словами сантехник расположился на ступенях лестницы, в позе приуставшего путника*.

Answer (score 1):

Если используем настоящее время, то хотим сказать, что либо сейчас уже располагается (место изменилось), либо всё так же располагается (место осталось прежним).

*Девушка тут же метнулась к шкафу, который располагается слева от стола.* || Подходит для речи экскурсовода в музее. Он рассказывает про историю с некой девушкой. А тот шкаф **сейчас уже** находится в музее и располагается слева от стола. Что-то другое сложно придумать.

Если смысл — "***всё так же** располагается*", то так не скажут.

Так что нужно прошедшее.